# Kubernetes Helm pod restart infinitly

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy Spinnaker into a Kubernetes cluster. To do the trick, I 
 use Halyard which uses Helm.
While I'm trying to run my Helm pod I have the following output:

```
Cluster "default" set.
Context "default" created.
User "user" set.
Context "default" modified.
Switched to context "default".
Creating /home/spinnaker/.helm 
Creating /home/spinnaker/.helm/repository 
Creating /home/spinnaker/.helm/repository/cache 
Creating /home/spinnaker/.helm/repository/local 
Creating /home/spinnaker/.helm/plugins 
Creating /home/spinnaker/.helm/starters 
Creating /home/spinnaker/.helm/cache/archive 
Creating /home/spinnaker/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml 
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com 
Adding local repo with URL: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts 
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/spinnaker/.helm.
Tiller (the Helm server-side component) has been upgraded to the current version.
Happy Helming!
```

All seems correct. But my pod raise a **CrashLoopBackOff** event without any other error and my pod restart again for no apparent reason.

The dockerfile I'm using to build the helm docker image is the following:

```
FROM gcr.io/spinnaker-marketplace/halyard:stable

ARG GCP_SPINNAKER_GCR_KEY

# install helm
WORKDIR /home/spinnaker

# get helm
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/helm/master/scripts/get > get_helm.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\/usr\/local\/bin/\/home\/spinnaker/g' get_helm.sh

# sudo user workaround
RUN sed -i 's/sudo //g' get_helm.sh
RUN chmod u+x get_helm.sh

# add the current folder to the path 
ENV PATH="/home/spinnaker:${PATH}"

# install helm
RUN ./get_helm.sh

# importing the configuration script
ADD shell/halyard-configure.sh .

# auhtorize the spinnaker user to execute the configuration script
USER root
RUN chown -R spinnaker halyard-configure.sh
USER spinnaker

# create the gcp key directory for docker registry
RUN mkdir -p ~/.gcp
RUN echo $GCP_SPINNAKER_GCR_KEY | base64 -d > ~/.gcp/gcr-account.json

ENTRYPOINT [ "./halyard-configure.sh" ] 

CMD "/opt/halyard/bin/halyard"
```

And here is the content of the **halyard-configure.sh** shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# configure kubectl
kubectl config set-cluster default --server=https://kubernetes.default --certificate-authority=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
kubectl config set-context default --cluster=default
token=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
kubectl config set-credentials user --token=$token
kubectl config set-context default --user=user
kubectl config use-context default

# configure helm
helm init --service-account tiller --upgrade
```

Comment: If your pod is in crashloopbackoff what info does the following give: kubectl describe pod $POD_NAME

Comment: You can debug this with logs or describing pods details, It'll provide most of the details required for debugging any issue. Following commands will help you with that.
Kubectl logs -f <pod_name>
kubectl describe pods <pod_name>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entrypoint script needs to end with the magic line `exec "$@"`.

In Docker in general, a container startup launches the container entrypoint, passing it the command as parameters.  (A Kubernetes pod spec refers to these parts as "command" and "args".)  Once the entrypoint completes, the container exits.  Since your entrypoint script just runs `kubectl config` and `helm init` commands which all complete promptly, the container exits almost immediately; when it does, Kubernetes restarts it; and when it has to restart it more than two or three times, it goes into `CrashLoopBackOff` state.

The usual way to get around this is to set up the entrypoint script to do any required first-time setup, then `exec` the command that was passed to it as parameters.  Then the command (in your case, `/opt/halyard/bin/halyard`) winds up being "the main container process", and has the magic process ID 1, and will receive signals at container termination time.

Also note that there is a reasonably standard [pattern for accessing the Kubernetes API from a pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod) that involves configuring a service account for the pod and using an official API, or else launching a `kubectl proxy` sidecar.  You might be able to use that in place of the manual setup steps you have here.  (I've never tried to launch Helm from inside a Kubernetes pod, though.)

Comment: I've totally refactored my script to be more compliant with your comments. Now it's working. **CMD "/opt/halyard/bin/halyard"** was ignored on startup.